# MySQLdb commit() method not saving data

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I've got a class to perform all the SQL tasks in my code. The problem is when I call a method inside this class to update the database, the `self.dbConn.commit()` line is not saving the data.

What am I missing? I'm sure it's a newbie error but I can't find the problem.

If more code examples are needed I can provide them.

Cheers!

This is the class itself:

```
class dbActivities:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dbConn = my.connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx")
        self.dbCursor = self.dbConn.cursor()

    def updateDB(self, sql):
        try:
            self.dbCursor.execute(sql)
            self.dbConn.commit()
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

And that's how I'm calling the method:

```
dbHandler.updateDB("UPDATE xxx SET token = {}, WHERE xxx = {}".format(xxx, xxx))
```

Comment: Also, I would also remove connection opening from constructors and use the `with` statement to ensure proper disposal. Use [connection pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html) to avoid "the overhead" of re-opening connections.

Comment: Also, don't use string formatting for data in SQL statements. Use placeholders stead: [*placeholders **prevent SQL injection** and silly errors that may arise from unexpected data (and the resulting invalid SQL)*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Comment: Anyway, either 1) "0 rows were updated" or 2) *there is an Exception: **remove** the `try-except` to see the useful error*, possibly about invalid SQL (see previous comment for how to fix if it's a "quoting" error)

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you for your time and your tips! I was using placeholders but I just changed to a formatted strings to make sure that wasn't the problem. The problem was that I forgot some quotes in the SQL syntax. Also I'll start using connectors and wrapping the SQL in with statments. Thanks another time!